Disable block editor pre-publish sidebar for custom post type
I'm trying to disable pre-publish sidebar in the block editor programmatically for a specific post type.
I use the following code to disable globally and it's working fine but struggle to disable it for a specific post type.
window.wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').disablePublishSidebar();

